# Cannot read property of undefined in render loop

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React. I am trying to associate an on-click handler to a component rendered in a loop in React, but am getting a prop undefined error. My code is as follows:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './ImageGallery.css';

class ImageGallery extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.selectImage = this.selectImage.bind(this);
  }

  selectImage(e){
    console.log(e.target);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      this.props.images.map(function(e, i){
        return <img alt={i} key={i} src={e} className="thumbnail" onClick={this.selectImage}/>
      })
    )
  }
}

export default ImageGallery;
```

Unfortunately the documentation around lists and keys is not very supportive for my scenario, as it does not also cover events: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.htm

The error message is: `Cannot read property 'selectImage' of undefined`

Answer (score 4):

Replace your `map` callback to the following, using *arrow function*

```
this.props.images.map((e, i) => {
  return <img alt={i} key={i} src={e} className="thumbnail" onClick={this.selectImage}/>
})
```

Or save `this` before `return` statement

```
const that = this;
return (
  this.props.images.map(function(e, i){
    return <img alt={i} key={i} src={e} className="thumbnail" onClick={that.selectImage}/>
  })
)
```

It might be useful for you - how [`this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work) works in javascript.

Comment: My understanding is that the `this` keyword is lexically scoped to the immediate outer function. So that makes sense. But I assumed that by binding it to the class declaration (i.e. in the constructor), React would "know" which function to bind `this` to.
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can use an arrow function instead of `function` syntax, that way your `this` object will refer to the context outside of the function - e.g.

```
arr.map((e, i) => { /* 'this' refers to your component, not internal scope of the function */ })
```

Answer (score 0):

You have using this into a map() function while rendering. It changes this `this` 
reference.

You can do like below. Notice the variable `me`

```
render() {
  let me = this;
  return (
    this.props.images.map(function(e, i){
      return <img alt={i} key={i} src={e} className="thumbnail" onClick={me.selectImage}/>
    })
  )
}
```